# Cannot execute binary file on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I cannot run build with error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: cannot execute binary file
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 126

[image]

Comment: Execute the command `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool` in your terminal and append the output to your post.

Answer (score 0):

In my case swift development snapshot was selected instead of xcode 9.2. here are the steps and image.

xcode on screen and click on xcode top menu bar.
Than go to toolchains option and check on xcode 9.2. thats it. 
[image]

Note: If no toolchain found in your xcode than download from [Here](https://swift.org/download/#releases) and install it. (after installation restart xcode). Happy Coding.

Comment: update answer now you can see under the xcode 9.2 there is toolchain option.